# Maintaining previous position in an EditorPane when the text is refreshed

Tags: java, swing, scroll

This is a problem that has vexed me for a number of years.   The user is scrolling through a text document contained in an JEditorPane which is in turn contained in a JScrollPane.   The user performs some function using a button which changes the text (it highlights certain sections of the text).   I then refresh the document in the JeditorPane to reflect the highlighting (using html tags).  But when I do this, the document scrolls back to the top.   I want the document to stay in the same position that the user was in right before taking the action.   Note, the user has not selected any text in the document so I can't scroll to a selection point (that technique does work if text is selected, but alas I can't do it in this case).    How do I preserve the position in the JScrollPane and scroll to the position that the user was at prior to taking the action?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all of these potential solutions.   Unfortunately, for whatever reason, they didn't work.     This is the code that actually solved the problem for me.

/* This code is executed, before the JeditorPane is updated: */

```
int spoint = detailpane.scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
```

/* Then to restore the scroll to where it was before the update, the following code is executed*/

```
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
    public void run()
    {
    detailpane.scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(spoint);
    }
    });
```

/* Note because of the usual weirdnesses associated with Swing which is not thread safe, you need to enclosed the setValue within in a Runnable. */

Answer (score 2):

You can use JViewport.scrollRectToVisible() to jump to a certain section of a document in a JScrollPane. You can snapshot the current position before performing the action with JViewPort.getViewRect()

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html

Answer (score 1):

> Note, the user has not selected any text in the document so I can't scroll to a selection point

Get the selection indices before updating, then call `setCaretPosition(previousStart)` then `moveCaretPosition(previousEnd)` afterwards.

Comment: As stated in my initial post, there is no caret position to get.   The text is not being selected.

Comment: @Elliott: Your caret position is 0 or someplace outside the viewport?

Comment: It's always zero since the user is not selecting text in the editorPane.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
Point p = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewPosition();
// do stuff
scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition();
```